# Using HTML Tags received from Api call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I receive a element from a rest API. It was as follows:

" **Hyderabad Adventure & Trekker's club (HAT's)**  "

The above written bold text is with b tags.

It is coming as it is(with b tags written separately) but I want that Content under  tag should be bold in my html and there is line break.

Comment: use `ng-bind-html`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml#!/

Comment: thanx working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work **:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope,$sce) {
  $scope.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml("<b>Hyderabad Adventure & Trekker's club (HAT's)</b>");
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <span ng-bind-html="myHTML"></span>
</div>
</div>
```